# What is the meaning of the hex value syntax with an underscore? eg:parameter FOO = 20'h0002_0

Tags: parameters, syntax, verilog, system-verilog

Pretty much just the title. What does that underscore mean? How is this different from:

```
parameter FOO = 20'h00020;
```

I don't know what to look for to find an answer to this question as I don't know what this type of syntax is called.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the IEEE Std (1800-2009), section "5.7.1 Integer literal constants":

> The underscore character (_) shall be legal anywhere in a number
>   except as the first character. The underscore character is ignored.
>   This feature can be used to break up long numbers for readability
>   purposes.

So, `20'h00020` is the same as `20'h0002_0`.

I found this by searching in the above spec for "underscore".

Answer (score 5):

It means nothing. It's just a separator to make long numbers easier to read, like a comma which separates groups of three digits in a long number (e.g. 1,000,000).